# passing a returned pointer of a dynamical two-dimensional array to a sub-function and addressing the array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, multidimensional-array

My issue is the following: I am making a pointer to a dynamic two dimensional array on the heap. This is done in a subfunction "Production" which fills in the elements of the table (array) and returns the pointer of the array to the main(). There I want to give the pointer as a parameter for another function "PrintTable"; which cout's the table. My issue is that the returned pointer is actually a one dimensional array (c++) and I don't know how to adress it to get the second row of the array..
Let me try to explain it to you:

So first I have a function which returns a pointer to a two-dimensional array.

```
int* Production(int num1, string name1[], int num2, string name2[])
{

int** productionTable=new int*[num1];
for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
{
      productionTable[i] = new int[num2];
}


for (int i=0;i<num1;i++)
{
cout << "\nGive production " << name1[i]<<endl;
for (int j=0;j<num2;j++)
{
    cout << "On " << name2[j] << " : ";
    cin >> productionTable[i][j];
}
}
return* productionTable;
}
```

in the main () I let the returned pointer point to a pointer productiontable so it exists in the main.

```
int* productionTable=Production(num1, name1[], num2, name2[])
```

Then I call function printTable() witch has to output the 2dimensional array as a table. so I want to use this pointer as an argument for another function; to cout the elements from this array.

```
PrintTable(num1, name1[], num2, name2[], productionTable);
```

This function looks like this:

```
void printTable(int num1, string name1[], int num2, string name2[],int* productionTable)
{
cout << left <<setw(10)<< "";
for (int i=0;i<num2;i++)
{
    cout << left <<setw(10)<< name2[i];
}
cout<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<num1;i++)
{
cout << setw(10)<<name1[i]<<"";
for (int j=0;j<num2;j++)
{
    cout << left <<setw(10)<< productionTable[i+j];

}cout<<endl;
}
}
```

My problem is that I can't get the function to output the second row right. How should i adress the second parameter of the array. So far i've read i should make the table point to [COLindex * COL_size + ROWindex]. I've tried it but i dan't get him to print the second row. What should the COL_size paramter be?

Comment: If you're using `**` in C++, there's a good chance you're doing something wrong.  You should strongly consider using containers.

Comment: then tell me how i should make a pointer to a dynamic 2 dimensional array. There are not a lot of alternatives..

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is one possibility.  `boost::multi_array<int,2>` is another.

Comment: Why does `Production` return a `int*` instead of the `int**` is creates internally?

Comment: As Oli Charlesworth said, containers are good for you ! But I guess that is an home work... So replace int* Production(int num1, string name1[], int num2, string name2[]) by int** Production(int num1, string name1[], int num2, string name2[]) and of course, return* productionTable; by return productionTable;

Comment: yeah i haven't seen vectors yet, so i had to do it with arrays.. but thanks for your answers and @OliCharlesworth and abarral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
int** productionTable=new int*[num1];
...
return* productionTable;
```

Basically, by the return, you return only the first row (or a pointer to it) discarding the rest of the table. To make it work, you could declare `Production` and `productionTable` (at all places) as `int**`, `return productionTable` in `Production` and use `productionTable[i][j]` for element retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to wade through the creation of your table fully, so there may well be problems there.  Just looking at the end bit though, it seems that you're trying to print a one-dimensional array in two dimensions, which is straightforward, you just need to keep track of how far into the array you are on each row.

For each row, you need to offset your column index by (number of columns * number of rows already printed).

It looks like `num1` is the total number of rows and `num2` is the total number of columns.  `i` is the number of rows completed already.  So `i*num2` is the offset required to read the row you are trying to print.

```
for (int i=0;i<num1;i++)
{
  cout << setw(10)<<name1[i]<<"";
  for (int j=0;j<num2;j++)
  {
    cout << left <<setw(10)<< productionTable[i*num2+j];
  }
  cout<<endl;
}
```